Does Flink have a mechanism to clean each TaskManager's resources when cancelling a job?
I'm currently running a Flink application (Java) with a few TaskManagers. This application uses a HikariDataSource to connect to an Oracle database, and each TaskManager JVM ends up with its own instance of HikariDataSource. Now, when I cancel my job, I naturally also want to close all the database connections my application is holding by calling HikariDataSource.close(). Is there any mechanism to force each TaskManager to call close() on its HikariDataSource instance?
I did try to close everything using my source function's cancel() function, but I found that Flink was only running 1 instance of source function on one of the TaskManagers. This meant that the connections were only released on the TaskManager running my source function, while the connections held by the other TaskManagers instead remained in the Oracle database (albeit marked "INACTIVE"). I'm aware that I could use brute force and run my source function on every task slot, but that seems like a poor solution.
Edit: I managed to close my connections in the close() function of my RichAsyncFunction instead, since that runs on all task slots.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
